# Hibernate Criteria creates a '?' in the generated SQL

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a sample web application. I am using MS SQL Server 2008 as database and hibernate + annotations to access the database. My hibernate configuration xml is as below.
The problem is, the Criteria.list() returns an empty list, and also I am seeing a '?' in the generated HSQL instead of the parameter I am passing in the Criteria.

```
<session-factory name="">
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:odbc:dbname</property>

    <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>       

     <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>       
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>

<mapping class="com.demo.Person" />
</session-factory>
```

This is my annotated bean

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "person")
    public class Person implements Serializable {

        public Person(){

        }
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "personid")
        private Integer personid;

        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "firstname")
        private String firstname;

        @Column(name = "lastname")
        private String lastname;

        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "phone")
        private String phone;

        @Column(name = "mobile")
        private String mobile;

        @Column(name = "street")
        private String street;

        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "city")
        private String city;

        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "country")
        private String country;

        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "bussinessowner")
        private int bussinessowner;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "resultid1")
        private Collection<Recent> recentCollection;

//setters & getters
}
```

**And the code I am running is**

```
Session session;
        List list = new ArrayList();
        try{
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("firstname", name, MatchMode.START));
        list= criteria.list();
        System.out.println(list.size());

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Generated HSQL :**

```
Hibernate: select this_.personid as personid2_0_,  this_.city as city2_0_, this_.country as country2_0_, this_.firstname as firstname2_0_, this_.lastname as lastname2_0_ from person this_ where this_.firstname like ?
```

Other than this I am not getting any exception either. Can you please help me out with this.
Thanks !

Comment: It seems no error in code. have you cheched manually writing query to DB, does it returns any result?

Comment: Yes, If I execute the query in the management studio, it returns the result. But in the above code, its returning empty list.

Comment: "?" is for prepared statement - no error here. When you execute the query manually what do you replace "?" with?

Comment: The `?` is just the sign that the value of `name` is passed to the JDBC driver as a parameter (as it *should be*!) and not directly in the SQL clause. I suspect the reason for the empty return list is something else.

Comment: okay, But if i execute the same query in management studio, then I am able to get the results. Am I missing something else ?

Comment: And what may HSQL be? What you show is plain SQL.

Comment: Can you tell what you are passing in the name variable? and when you are running query in management studio what string you are replacing with ?

Comment: remove MatchMode.START and try?

Comment: Tried removing MatchMode.START, but no change in output

Comment: @RAS, I am using annotations.

Comment: Updated beans in the question

Answer (score 0):

Does changing it to `criteria.add(Restrictions.like("firstname", name + "%"));` help?
And, by the way, `?` is correct parameter placeholder for `jbdc` statements.

Comment: I tried the same using `Query` and hardcoding the query, this way it works fine. But using `Criteria` is not fetching any results !

Comment: are you sure you run both query on one database instance? Maybe it point to different databases, thats what you can get different results.

Comment: I have only one database in my system and I am sure I am running both the queries on the same db

Comment: i see you 're using different fields in your query, as you mentioned in previuos comment. Just change `firstname` to `name` in criteria and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("firstname", name, MatchMode.START));
```

try

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("firstname", name, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

OR

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("firstname", name, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

It will gerenerate SQL as **firstname like '%abcd%'** , if you pass firstname as "abcd"

Can you simply try this

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession(); 
List<Person> personList = session.createQuery("Select * from Person p where p.firstname like 'rake%'").list();

System.out.println("Person result :" + personList .size());
```

Comment: I tried the same using Query and hardcoding the query, this way it works fine. But using Criteria is not fetching any results !

Comment: ANYWHERE also returns an empty list :(

Comment: Do you have records in database table for that first name ? Please share your SQL query which you are executing and which returns the result

Comment: I do have records in that table. The SQL Query returning the result is : `SELECT * FROM person WHERE firstname LIKE 'rake%'`

Comment: @Rakesh 'name' and 'firstname' are different fields?

Comment: Sorry, its `firstname`, my bad

Comment: I hope you are connecting to the same database from hibernate also ?

Comment: @RahulAgrawal, using the above query is working, But why is criteria not working is my question.

Comment: If this Query works, then criteria should also work. Instead of this line in your code list= criteria.list(); Try List<Person> list= (List<Person>) criteria.list();  I think there seems to be typecast issue with criteria

Answer (score 0):

@Rakesh Try below code:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("firstname", name +"%"));
```

Answer (score 0):

'?' is the place holder for parameters in JDBC statements. You can't see its actual value, that's all. There is no problem with it, just the tracing with hibernate remains incomplete.

If you want to see the actual value for '?', then you have to use an extra product like [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/).